# Continuity of motivic cohomology under direct limit

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, motivic-cohomology

Given the motivic complexes $\mathbb{Z}(n)$ on the big Zariski site of finite type smooth $k$-schemes denoted by $FinSm_k$, we pullback it to the smooth $k$-schemes i.e. $Sm_k$. For example for a smooth $k$-scheme $X$ with structure map $f$, the complex on the big Zariski site of $X$ is $f^*(\mathbb{Z}(n))$ (pulled back from the big Zariski site of $\text{Spec}(k)$). Does the sheaf cohomology of this extended motivic cohomology from $FinSm_k$ to all $Sm_k$ coincide with the motivic cohomology $\mathbb{Z}(n)$ if we directly define it on $Sm_k$?

A simpler way to ask this question is the following example: Does the motivic cohomology of the function field coincide with the direct limit of motivic cohomology groups of all Zariski opens? (I believe the answer is positive but cannot figure out a simple proof)